# Return ColumnNames from Select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

First i written **select query with join** for retrieving required columns. After that using **Top 0** i got the required columns. 
Which will come like this,
[image: Which will come like this]

i dont want any records. but i need the result of only the column names like this,

[image]

**sample code:**

```
select Top 0 *tablename*.* from my *tablename*
(some joins and where conditions)
```

*tablename* => contains dynamic columns (After doing joins)

Comment: are you perhaps looking for a PIVOT? it's hard to say from your question.

Comment: @MitchWheat no, im not expecting pivot

Comment: The suspense is killing me.....

Comment: Far from clear, but what if you got the column names from querying say syscolumns, Wouldn't need the dynamic sql either, just join to systables.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson its not a sys columns columns and table names are dynamic...

Comment: You've lost me. Select Top 0 * From **TableName** versus Select * From Systables Where [name] = @TableName...

Comment: @Horaciux s but its not working. because my table and column is not a sys object which is dynamic fields.

Comment: @Karthik Well, that still be an object but from another database, it is in system database TempDB

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on @Tony Hopkinson suggestion

```
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t 
 INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name = @table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a cursour (i.e. you can use Transact-SQL), then the `sp_describe_cursor_columns` ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182755(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) may help you.

If you want to do this from outside SQL Server, all database access technologies provide some kind of  API to access metadata for a result set.